# htaccess remove .php extension on specific file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to be able to rewrite **a specific page** so that the .php extension is removed:

```
http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/my-landing-page.php
```

to:

```
http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/my-landing-page
http://www.mywordpresswebsite.com/my-landing-page/
```

Again, I need to remove the extension for **one file in particular**, not every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteRule ^web/?$ web.php  [NC]
```

Comment: This will remove the extension for all files. I'm aiming at only one file in particular

Comment: I'm glad, if you have any issue please comment here!

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress users that want to remove the extension for a specific file, make sure to include it **before** the index rewrite rule, so it can match it. This works to remove the .php extension from a specific file (validation.php) in a Wordpress Environment (note how I added the rule after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`), making yourwebsite.com/validation works.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^validation$ validation.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```